# JavaScript edit Array inside Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it somehow possible to push items to an array inside of a JavaScript object

Here my code:

```
function test() {
this.array = [];

this.addItem = function() {
    this.array.push("someString");
}

this.removeItem = function() {
    this.array.remove(0);
}}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Do you have some reason to think that the code you've provided doesn't work? You should provide a *complete* [mcve] showing how you are trying to use it and demonstrating why you think it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with Objects, you can use ***Javascript ES6***

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.array = [];
  }
    
  addItem(item) {
    this.array.push(item);
  }
    
  removeItem() {
    this.array.splice(0, 1);
  }
  
  removeItemByIndex(index) {
    this.array.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

const test = new Test();
test.addItem('Some Item');
test.addItem('Some Item 2');
console.log(test.array);

test.removeItem();
console.log(test.array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code-

```js
var obj = {
  numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}

obj.numbers.push(5)
console.log(obj.numbers)
```